# Delay mouseout/hover with CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions

I've got a box that changes size when being hovered. However, I would like to delay the mouseout stage, so that the box keep the new size for a few seconds, before getting the old size back.

```
div {
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all;    
}

div:hover {
    width:130px;
}
```

Is this possible to do WITHOUT Javascript and only CSS3? I only have to care about supporting **webkit**.

Comment: have you tried css3 animation property? i have tried some things with animation property, but i am not sure that is what you want. but if you want i can give you that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
div {
    width: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: .5s all;   
    -webkit-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -moz-transition: .5s all;   
    -moz-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -ms-transition: .5s all;   
    -ms-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -o-transition: .5s all;   
    -o-transition-delay: 5s; 
    transition: .5s all;   
    transition-delay: 5s; 
}

div:hover {
    width:130px;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

This will trigger the mouseover state right away, but wait 5 sec till the mouseout is triggered.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLg1gL7y/1/)

Comment: edited to add non webkit prefixes too - it's just good practice

Comment: on the "div" tag definition, isn't specifying "transition:" and "transition-delay" essentially a duplicate? The first value of the transition spec IS the delay value, no?

Comment: @Screenack No, the first value is the duration of the transition - how long it takes to complete once it gets going.

Comment: awesome use of transitions, patad.

Answer (score 9):

transition can be declared as

```
transition: .5s all 5s
```

(shorthand, the first number is duration, the second number is delay)
then you don't need the separate transition-delay

sorry, can't add as a comment as I don't have enough points