# How to delay the disappearance of an element on mouseout

Tags: html, css

I got a li element on my page which is `<li class="basket last items">`. 
If the user hovers over that li another div is shown which is `<div class="articles">`. I want to delay the disappearance of the div on mouseout.

My current css rules:

```
#headlinks li.basket div.articles {
    padding:5px;
    width:380px;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #405ade;
    -webkit-transition: display .5s all;   
    -webkit-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -moz-transition: .5s all;   
    -moz-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -ms-transition: .5s all;   
    -ms-transition-delay: 5s; 
    -o-transition: .5s all;   
    -o-transition-delay: 5s; 
    transition: .5s all;   
    transition-delay: 5s; 
}
#headlinks li.basket:hover div.articles {
    z-index:1000;
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    -transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

I thought with that rules the mouseout should be delayed by 5 seconds but it's not working.

**Edit:** Here is a jsfiddle of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/21tn6bq6/ I left out unnecessary css but basically that's my problem. I want the div to stay for some more seconds after mouseout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay mouseout/hover with CSS3 transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393125/delay-mouseout-hover-with-css3-transitions)

Comment: I read that post but as you can see I tried to use it and it's not working. That's why I need help.

Comment: You may need to create a demo (here in a snippet or at http://jsfiddle.net). "It's not working" doesn't help much.

Comment: You cant transition non-numeric values like `block` and `none`. What would thew mid-point of the transition look like for example. There isn't a  `display: half-block-half-none` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` property is not "animable", the `transitions` don't work with it. You need to change it to `opacity` or something else. And also you need to swap the `transitions` properties to get the effect that you want.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/21tn6bq6/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your delays switched. Your current CSS shows a delay on mouseover, not mouseout

Comment: I got 0 delay on the :hover action because I want to delay the mouseout not the hover, I thought it should work that way.