# Delay fadeOut menu jquery

Tags: jquery, menu, delay, fadeout

I am new at Jquery and I am trying to make a menu to show up on hover with fadeIn and when the mouse leaves to start a delay and then close the menu with fadeout.

My code so far...
I made a jsFiddle too [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/36/)

```js
$('#menu > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").stop().fadeIn(120);
  $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  $(this).find("ul:first").stop().delay(2000).fadeOut(120);
  $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: The fiddle works (ul fades after 2sec). What is the problem?

Comment: It has problems when you hover and select the menu;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sequence of `delay` and `stop` and use longer `fadeOut` duration.

```
$(this).find("ul:first").delay(2000).stop().fadeOut(500);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/YGB5G/39/

**EDIT**

You can also use `hover` as follow:

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).find("ul:first").finish().fadeIn(120);
    $(this).find('> a').addClass('active');
}, function (e) {
    $(this).find("ul:first").finish().delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
    $(this).find('> a').removeClass('active');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/YGB5G/43/

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using pure css using the `transition` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) and the `:hover` selector. The trick is you that you need to use the `opacity:0;` property instead of the `display:none;` to hide your sub-menus because you cannot apply transitions on the `display` property.

```
#menu ul, #menu2 ul {
...
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
opacity:0;
}
#menu li:hover > ul, #menu2 li:hover > ul {
    opacity:1
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/42/

Also notice that the second level of dropdown menus is displayed the same way. Which is not the case in other answers.

## EDIT

you can use  `transition-delay: Xs;` to add a delay of X seconds to the effect on mouseout. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393125/delay-mouseout-hover-with-css3-transitions) post. Here a demo with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/YGB5G/44/

Answer (score 0):

By using foolowing way you can do fadeOut.

`$("#row_id").fadeOut('slow',function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        });`

You can also use time in millisecond in place of 'slow' without ''.