# Delay In Menu Hover For Mouse Out

Tags: javascript, php, css, joomla

I have use RocketTheme Joomla Templates. And use to RokNavMenu.

I have Try to Delay for Menu hover.

I want used following css for Delay in menu hover. And it's working. Please check link - www.test2.guru99.com/

```
.gf-menu li .dropdown {
transition: opacity 5.0s ease-out 0.0s;
}
```

My Requirement is - when the mouse is moved out menu still appear for seconds.

Comment: This is purely a css issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay mouseout/hover with CSS3 transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393125/delay-mouseout-hover-with-css3-transitions)